# Merge data frames from a list with each other

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, plyr

#### What I need:

I have a huge data frame with the following columns (and some more, but these are not important). Here's an example:

```
    user_id video_id group_id    x   y
1         1        0        0   39 108
2         1        0        0   39 108
3         1       10        0  135 180
4         2        0        0   20 123
```

User, video and group IDs are factors, of course. For example, there are 20 videos, but each of them has several "observations" for each user and group.

I'd like to transform this data frame into the following format, where there are as many `x.N`, `y.N` as there are users (`N`).

```
video_id  x.1   y.1  x.2  y.2  …
       0   39   108   20  123
```

So, for video `0`, the x and y values from user 1 are in columns `x.1` and `y.1`, respectively. For user 2, their values are in columns `x.2`, `y.2`, and so on.

#### What I've tried:

I made myself a list of data frames that are solely composed of all the `x, y` observations for each `video_id`:

```
summaryList = dlply(allData, .(user_id), function(x) unique(x[c("video_id","x","y")]) )
```

That's how it looks like:

```
List of 15
 $ 1 :'data.frame': 20 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ video_id: Factor w/ 20 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 1 11 8 5 12 9 20 13 7 10 ...
  ..$ x       : int [1:20] 39 135 86 122 28 167 203 433 549 490 ...
  ..$ y       : int [1:20] 108 180 164 103 187 128 185 355 360 368 ...
 $ 2 :'data.frame': 20 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ video_id: Factor w/ 20 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 2 14 15 4 20 6 19 3 13 18 ...
  ..$ x       : int [1:20] 128 688 435 218 528 362 299 134 83 417 ...
  ..$ y       : int [1:20] 165 117 135 179 96 328 332 563 623 476 ...
```

#### Where I'm stuck:

What's left to do is:

- <s>Merge each data frame from the `summaryList` with each other, based on the `video_id`. I can't find a nice way to access the actual data frames in the list, which are `` summaryList[1]$`1` ``, `` summaryList[2]$`2` ``, et cetera.</s>

  @James found out a partial solution:

  ```
  Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,by="video_id"),summaryList)
  ```
- Ensure the column names are renamed after the user ID and not kept as-is. Right now my `summaryList` doesn't contain any info about the user ID, and the output of `Reduce` has duplicate column names like `x.x y.x x.y y.y x.x y.x` and so on.

How do I go about doing this? Or is there any easier way to get to the result than what I'm currently doing?

Comment: Can you provide a subset of your data? I'm thinking `Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,by="video_id"),summaryList)` might do the trick

Comment: Can you provide a (simplified) example of your input data.frame and the expected output? I'm having difficulties understanding what you want to do.

Comment: @Roland I added a small example. Here's [the whole dataset](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Lv7RqC0i) just in case.

Comment: @James That *almost* works, only the columns are `video_id  x.x y.x  x.y y.y  x.x y.x`, etc., so not named after the user IDs.

Comment: @slhck Try using `names(reducedData)[-1] <- do.call(function(...) paste(...,sep="."),expand.grid(letters[24:25],names(summaryList)))` afterwards.

Comment: @James That does the trick. Feel free to post your lines of code as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Reduce` does the trick:

```
reducedData <- Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,by="video_id"),summaryList)
```

… but you need to fix the `names` afterwards:

```
names(reducedData)[-1] <- do.call(function(...) paste(...,sep="."),expand.grid(letters[24:25],names(summaryList)))
```

The result is:

```
   video_id  x.1 y.1  x.2 y.2  x.3 y.3  x.4 y.4  x.5 y.5  x.6 y.6  x.7 y.7  x.8
1         0   39 108  899 132   61 357  149 298 1105 415  148 208  442 200  210
2         1 1125  70  128 165 1151 390  171 587  623 623   80 643  866 310  994
```

Answer (score 4):

I am still somewhat confused. However, I guess you simply want to `melt` and `dcast`.

```
library(reshape2)
d <- melt(allData,id.vars=c("user_id","video_id"), measure.vars=c("x","y"))
dcast(d,video_id~user_id+variable,value.var="value",fun.aggregate=mean)
```

Resulting in:

```
 video_id  1_x 1_y  2_x 2_y  3_x 3_y  4_x 4_y  5_x 5_y  6_x 6_y  7_x 7_y  8_x 8_y  9_x 9_y 10_x 10_y 11_x 11_y 12_x 12_y 14_x 14_y 15_x 15_y 16_x 16_y
1         0   39 108  899 132   61 357  149 298 1105 415  148 208  442 200  210 134   58 244  910  403  152   52 1092  617 1012  114 1105  424  548  394
2         1 1125  70  128 165 1151 390  171 587  623 623   80 643  866 310  994 114  854 129  781  306  672   -1 1096  354  525  524  150
```

Comment: I had to get rid of a few exta columns, see the edit to your post, but this works as well, thanks! I'm somewhat unexperienced with `reshape`, so could you perhaps explain what `dcast` does here or why it creates the columns in the first place?

Comment: `dcast` simply transforms from long format (most used with statistical software) to wide format (loved by Excel folks). The formula defines which variables become column headers. `melt`is the inverse transformation.